# How to sort a collection of points so that they set up one after another?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains coordinates of points:

```
class Point
{
   int x, y;
}
ArrayList<Point> myPoints;
```

of such an image for example:

[image]

The problem is that these points are set chaotically in the ArrayList and I would like to sort them so that 2 points lying next to each other on the image are also one after another in the ArrayList. I can't come up with some good idea or algorithm to solve such a sorting... Are there some known methods of solving such problems?

edit:
The shape cannot cross over itself and let's assume that only shapes looking similarly like this can occur.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this the only input you'll ever get? What should happen if the shape crosses over itself? This question is too broad for StackOverflow and will probably be closed.

Comment: The shape cannot cross over itself and let's assume that only shapes looking like this can occur. How might it be too broad?... Asking for programming algorithm is too broad?

Comment: With shapes like the above, you can probably get away with picking an arbitrary point, then finding the nearest point (in Euclidean space), and so on.  With more complex shapes, that may not be sufficient, in which case you may need to consider the current gradient.  Even that will have limits.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody: Dijkstra's algorithm is about shorted-paths in graphs, right?  How does that relate to this?

Comment: Aw come on, close-voters, I was one minute before posting an answer containing an MVCE... :-(

Comment: ... Why a small group of people who think diffrently are able to close a thread that actually attracted an interest of many people? This is just wrong

Comment: Pick starting point P(0), then on every step i look for P(i+1) such that it is geometrically the closest to P(i), excluding points that already are transferred into sorted array. Complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: I upvoted because I think this will be a good interview question.  I like asking interview questions where the information is a bit incomplete, but forces discussion and thinking based on assumptions (hopefully they validate their assumptions with me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My thinking is that you first need a mathematical definition of your ordering.  I suggest (Note, this definition wasn't clear in the original question, left here for completeness):

Starting with placing any point in the sequence, then perpetually append to the sequence the point closest to the current point and that hasn't already been appended to the sequence, until all points are appended to the sequence.

Thus with this definition of the ordering, you can derive a simple algorithm for this

```
ArrayList<point> orderedList = new ArrayList<point>();

orderedList.add(myList.remove(0)); //Arbitrary starting point

while (myList.size() > 0) {
   //Find the index of the closest point (using another method)
   int nearestIndex=findNearestIndex(orderedList.get(orderedList.size()-1), myList);

   //Remove from the unorderedList and add to the ordered one
   orderedList.add(myList.remove(nearestIndex));
}
```

The above is pretty universal (regardless of the algorithm for finding the next point).  Then the "findNearestIndex" method could be defined as:

```
//Note this is intentially a simple algorithm, many faster options are out there
int findNearestIndex (point thisPoint, ArrayList listToSearch) {
    double nearestDistSquared=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    int nearestIndex;
    for (int i=0; i< listToSearch.size(); i++) {
        point point2=listToSearch.get(i);
        distsq = (thisPoint.x - point2.x)*(thisPoint.x - point2.x) 
               + (thisPoint.y - point2.y)*(thisPoint.y - point2.y);
        if(distsq < nearestDistSquared) {
            nearestDistSquared = distsq;
            nearestIndex=i;
        }
    }
    return nearestIndex;
}
```

Update:
Since the question was revised to largely adopt the definition I used, I took out some of the caveats.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution for you: our goal is to construct a path that visits each of points in your list exactly once before it loops back. We can construct paths recursively: we can pick any point from the original list as our starting point and make a trivial path that consists only of a single node. Then we can extend an already constructed path by appending a point that we haven't visited yet.

Then we assume that we can find a good order for the original list of points by making sure by choosing the path that has the smallest length. Here, by length I don't mean number of points in the path, but the total sum of the Euclidian distance between each pair of adjacent points on the path.

The only problem is: given such a path, which point should we append next? In theory, we'd have to try out all possibilities to see which one leads to the best overall path.

The main trick that the code below employs is that it uses the following heuristic: in each step where we have to append a new point to the path constructed so far, pick the point that minimizes the average distance between two adjacent points.

It should be noted that it would be a bad idea to include in this the "loop distance" between the last point on the path and the first point: as we keep adding points, we move away from the first path point more and more. If we included the distance between the two end points, this would severely affect the average distance between all adjacent pairs, and thus hurt our heuristic.

Here's a simple auxiliary class to implement the path construction outlined above:

```java
/**
 * Simple recursive path definition: a path consists 
 * of a (possibly empty) prefix and a head point.
 */
class Path {
    private Path prefix;
    private Point head;
    private int size;
    private double length;

    public Path(Path prefix, Point head) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.head = head;

        if (prefix == null) {
            size = 1;
            length = 0.0;
        } else {
            size = prefix.size + 1;

            // compute distance from head of prefix to this new head
            int distx = head.x - prefix.head.x;
            int disty = head.y - prefix.head.y;
            double headLength = Math.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

            length = prefix.length + headLength;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the actual heuristic search algorithm.

```java
/**
 * Implements a search heuristic to determine a sort
 * order for the given <code>points</code>.
 */
public List<Point> sort(List<Point> points) {
    int len = points.size();

    // compares the average edge length of two paths
    Comparator<Path> pathComparator = new Comparator<Path>() {
        public int compare(Path p1, Path p2) {
            return Double.compare(p1.length / p1.size, p2.length / p2.size);
        }
    };

    // we use a priority queue to implement the heuristic
    // of preferring the path with the smallest average
    // distance between its member points
    PriorityQueue<Path> pq = new PriorityQueue<Path>(len, pathComparator);
    pq.offer(new Path(null, points.get(0)));

    List<Point> ret = new ArrayList<Point>(len);
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        Path path = pq.poll();

        if (path.size == len) {
            // result found, turn path into list
            while (path != null) {
                ret.add(0, path.head);
                path = path.prefix;
            }
            break;
        }

        loop:
        for (Point newHead : points) {
            // only consider points as new heads that
            // haven't been processed yet
            for (Path check = path; check != null; check = check.prefix) {
                if (newHead == check.head) {
                    continue loop;
                }
            }

            // create new candidate path
            pq.offer(new Path(path, newHead));
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If you run this code on the sample points of your question, and then connect each adjacent pair of points from the returned list, you get the following picture:

[image]

Comment: woah, seems like another sophisticated solution! Lots of testing ahead of me. Btw, what's the "newPath" in your code? I thought it was just an overlooking and replacing it with the defined above "path" seemed to me reasonable but the code gives then memory exception. I'll try to figure it out and will have a deeper look into all of the solutions tommorow and carry out some performance tests as well

Comment: Yep, you're completely correct: I did some edits to my answer but didn't actually compile it, that's why the `newPath` artifact came up. I fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: However, on second thought, I think you should go with `Jared`'s answer. I was thinking that the additional overhead my answer introduces compared to his was warranted because my version could handle certain special cases better. But now I think it's not worth it, and you're better off with his approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `Sort` algorithm - it is more of a rearrangement to minimise a metric (the distance between consecutive points).

I'd attempt some kind of heuristic algorithm - something like:

1. Pick three consecutive points a, b, c.
2. If distance(a,c) < distance(a,b) then swap(a,b).
3. Repeat from 1.

It should be possible to calculate how many times you should need to cycle this to achieve a minimal arrangement or perhaps you could detect a minimal arrangement by finding no swaps during a run.

You may need to alternate the direction of your sweeps rather like the classic optimisation of bubble-sort.

**Added**

Experiment shows that this algorithm doesn't work but I've found one that does. Essentially, for each entry in the list find the closest other point and move it up to the next location.

```
private static class Point {

    final int x;
    final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }

    public double distance(Point b) {
        int dx = x - b.x;
        int dy = y - b.y;
        // Simple cartesian distance.
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
}

// Sample test data - forms a square.
Point[] points = new Point[]{
    new Point(0, 0),
    new Point(0, 1),
    new Point(0, 2),
    new Point(0, 3),
    new Point(0, 4),
    new Point(0, 5),
    new Point(0, 6),
    new Point(0, 7),
    new Point(0, 8),
    new Point(0, 9),
    new Point(1, 9),
    new Point(2, 9),
    new Point(3, 9),
    new Point(4, 9),
    new Point(5, 9),
    new Point(6, 9),
    new Point(7, 9),
    new Point(8, 9),
    new Point(9, 9),
    new Point(9, 8),
    new Point(9, 7),
    new Point(9, 6),
    new Point(9, 5),
    new Point(9, 4),
    new Point(9, 3),
    new Point(9, 2),
    new Point(9, 1),
    new Point(9, 0),
    new Point(8, 0),
    new Point(7, 0),
    new Point(6, 0),
    new Point(5, 0),
    new Point(4, 0),
    new Point(3, 0),
    new Point(2, 0),
    new Point(1, 0),};

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    List<Point> test = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(points, points.length));
    System.out.println("Before: " + test);
    Collections.shuffle(test);
    System.out.println("Shuffled: " + test);
    List<Point> rebuild = new ArrayList<>(test);
    rebuild.add(0, new Point(0, 0));
    rebuild(rebuild);
    rebuild.remove(0);
    System.out.println("Rebuilt: " + rebuild);
}

private void rebuild(List<Point> l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size() - 1; i++) {
        Point a = l.get(i);
        // Find the closest.
        int closest = i;
        double howClose = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < l.size(); j++) {
            double howFar = a.distance(l.get(j));
            if (howFar < howClose) {
                closest = j;
                howClose = howFar;
            }
        }
        if (closest != i + 1) {
            // Swap it in.
            Collections.swap(l, i + 1, closest);
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Before: [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5), (0,6), (0,7), (0,8), (0,9), (1,9), (2,9), (3,9), (4,9), (5,9), (6,9), (7,9), (8,9), (9,9), (9,8), (9,7), (9,6), (9,5), (9,4), (9,3), (9,2), (9,1), (9,0), (8,0), (7,0), (6,0), (5,0), (4,0), (3,0), (2,0), (1,0)]
Shuffled: [(9,6), (0,9), (0,8), (3,9), (0,5), (9,4), (0,7), (1,0), (5,0), (9,3), (0,1), (3,0), (1,9), (8,9), (9,8), (2,0), (2,9), (9,5), (5,9), (9,7), (6,0), (0,3), (0,2), (9,1), (9,2), (4,0), (4,9), (7,9), (7,0), (8,0), (6,9), (0,6), (0,4), (9,0), (0,0), (9,9)]
Rebuilt: [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5), (0,6), (0,7), (0,8), (0,9), (1,9), (2,9), (3,9), (4,9), (5,9), (6,9), (7,9), (8,9), (9,9), (9,8), (9,7), (9,6), (9,5), (9,4), (9,3), (9,2), (9,1), (9,0), (8,0), (7,0), (6,0), (5,0), (4,0), (3,0), (2,0), (1,0)]
```

which looks like what you are looking for.

The efficiency of the algorithm is not good - somewhere around O(n log n) - I hope you don't need to do this millions of times.

If you want the points to appear in a predictable order (say leftmost one at the start) you could add a fake point at the start of the list before rebuilding it and remove it after. The algorithm will always leave the first point alone.

Answer (score 1):

> I started this shortly after the question, but it had been delayed due to the question being put on hold. It's the simple approach that in the meantime also has been mentioned in the comments and other answers, but I'll post it here anyhow:

Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the simplest and most straightforward approach. The approach simply consists of picking an arbitrary point, and then continuing by always picking the point that is closest to the previous one. Of course, this has limitations:

- It may pick the wrong point, when there are sharp corners or cusps
- It's not very efficient, because it repeatedly does a search for the closest point

One approach for accelerating it could be to sort the points based on the x-coordinate, and then exploit this partial ordering in order to skip most of the points when looking for the next neighbor. But as long as you don't want to apply this to ten-thousands of points in a time-critical context, this should not be an issue.

The possible ambiguities, in turn, *may* be a problem, but considering that, one has to say that the problem is underspecified anyhow. In some cases, not even a human could decide which point is the appropriate "next" point - at least, when the problem is not extended to detect the "interior/exterior" of shapes (this is somewhat similar to the problem of [ambiguities in the marching cube algorithm:](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~lingrand/MarchingCubes/resources/marchingSAmbEx.gif) You just don't know what the *intended* path is).

Note that most of the code is not really important for your actual question, but ... you did not provide such a "stub" implementation. The relevant part is `=== marked ===`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SortShapePoints
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Shape shape = createExampleShape();
        List<Point2D> points = computePoints(shape, 6);
        Collections.shuffle(points);

        List<Point2D> sortedPoints = sortPoints(points);
        Path2D path = createPath(sortedPoints, true);
        f.getContentPane().add(new ShapePanel(points, path));

        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    //=== Relevant part starts here =========================================

    private static List<Point2D> sortPoints(List<Point2D> points)
    {
        points = new ArrayList<Point2D>(points);
        List<Point2D> sortedPoints = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        Point2D p = points.remove(0);
        sortedPoints.add(p);
        while (points.size() > 0)
        {
            int index = indexOfClosest(p, points);
            p = points.remove(index);
            sortedPoints.add(p);
        }

        return sortedPoints;
    }

    private static int indexOfClosest(Point2D p, List<Point2D> list)
    {
        double minDistanceSquared = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        int minDistanceIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            Point2D other = list.get(i);
            double distanceSquared = p.distanceSq(other);
            if (distanceSquared < minDistanceSquared)
            {
                minDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
                minDistanceIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minDistanceIndex;
    }

    //=== Relevant part ends here ===========================================


    private static Shape createExampleShape()
    {
        Area a = new Area();
        a.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 200, 200, 100)));
        a.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(260, 160, 100, 500)));
        a.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(220, 380, 180, 60)));
        a.add(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(180, 520, 260, 40)));
        return a;
    }

    private static List<Point2D> computePoints(Shape shape, double deviation)
    {
        List<Point2D> result = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, deviation);
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        Point2D newPoint = null;
        Point2D previousMove = null;
        Point2D previousPoint = null;
        while (!pi.isDone())
        {
            int segment = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            switch (segment)
            {
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                previousPoint = new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]);
                previousMove = new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]);
                break;

            case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                createPoints(previousPoint, previousMove, result, deviation);
                break;

            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                newPoint = new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]);
                createPoints(previousPoint, newPoint, result, deviation);
                previousPoint = new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]);
                break;

            case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
            case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
            default:
                // Should never occur
                throw new AssertionError("Invalid segment in flattened path!");
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void createPoints(Point2D p0, Point2D p1,
        List<Point2D> result, double deviation)
    {
        double dx = p1.getX() - p0.getX();
        double dy = p1.getY() - p0.getY();
        double d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
        int steps = (int) Math.ceil(d / deviation);
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            double alpha = (double) i / steps;
            double x = p0.getX() + alpha * dx;
            double y = p0.getY() + alpha * dy;
            result.add(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
        }
    }

    public static Path2D createPath(Iterable<? extends Point2D> points,
        boolean close)
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        Iterator<? extends Point2D> iterator = points.iterator();
        boolean hasPoints = false;
        if (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Point2D point = iterator.next();
            path.moveTo(point.getX(), point.getY());
            hasPoints = true;
        }
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Point2D point = iterator.next();
            path.lineTo(point.getX(), point.getY());
        }
        if (close && hasPoints)
        {
            path.closePath();
        }
        return path;
    }

}

class ShapePanel extends JPanel
{
    private final List<Point2D> points;
    private final Shape shape;

    public ShapePanel(List<Point2D> points, Shape shape)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(shape);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX() - 1, p.getY() - 1, 2, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from `Jared`'s answer?

Comment: @Thomas As mentioned above: I had started (and already *nearly* finished) this when the "This question was closed"-banner popped up. (Rather annoying, considering that the question already had 3 upvotes then and 9 now!). I did not want to let it get lost, even though similar answers have been posted in the meantime. It is a MVCE, maybe this also encourages others to try out other (better) approaches by implementing the `sortPoints` method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty open ended question but if you want them stored in a certain way you need to define the ordering more than "So that they are next to each other in the array"  You need to have a function where you can take two points and say, Point A is less than Point B or vice versa, or they are equal.

If you have that, then the algorithm you need to sort them is already implemented and you can use it by implementing a Comparator as SANN3 said.

As a side note, you might not want to store a shape as a set of points.  I think you might want to store them as a line?  You can use a cubic spline to get *almost* any shape you want then you could save on storage...

Answer (score 0):

I had a task to sort the points to represent a line. I decided to keep the full weight of the path and update it upon standard `Collection` operations accordingly. The solution should work in your case too. Just take the elements of this LinkedList `ps` and connect its head and tail. Also, you can add more operations like `PointXY get(int index)` etc. with a bit more forwarding to the underlying LinkedList in this composition. Finally, you should guard the collection with excessive defensive copies where necessary. I tried to keep it simple for the sake of brevity.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ContinuousLineSet implements Collection<PointXY> {
  LinkedList<PointXY> ps = new LinkedList<>(); // Exposed for simplicity
  private int fullPath = 0; // Wighted sum of all edges in ps

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return ps.size();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return ps.isEmpty();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return ps.contains(o);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<PointXY> iterator() {
    return ps.iterator();
  }

  @Override
  public Object[] toArray() {
    return ps.toArray();
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    return ps.toArray(a);
  }

  private int dist(PointXY a, PointXY b) {
    return (a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(PointXY e) {
    if (isEmpty())
      return ps.add(e);

    if (ps.getFirst().equals(e))
      return false;

    Iterator<PointXY> it = ps.iterator();
    PointXY previous = it.next();
    int asFirst = fullPath + dist(e, previous);
    int minPath = asFirst;
    int iMin = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      i++;
      PointXY next = it.next();
      if (next.equals(e))
        return false;

      int asBetween = fullPath - dist(previous, next) + dist(previous, e) + dist(e, next);
      if (asBetween < minPath) {
        iMin = i;
        minPath = asBetween;
      }

      previous = next;
    }

    int asLast = fullPath + dist(e, previous);
    if (asLast < minPath) {
      minPath = asLast;
      iMin = size();
    }

    fullPath = minPath;
    ps.add(iMin, e);
    return true;
  }

  public void reverse() {
    Collections.reverse(ps);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean remove(Object o) {
    PointXY last = null;
    for (Iterator<PointXY> it = iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      PointXY p = it.next();
      if (o.equals(p)) {
        int part1 = last != null ? dist(last, p) : 0;
        int part2 = it.hasNext() ? dist(p, it.next()) : 0;
        fullPath -= part1 + part2;
        break;
      }

      last = p;
    }

    return ps.remove(o);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    return ps.containsAll(c);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends PointXY> c) {
    boolean wasAdded = false;
    for (PointXY p : c) {
      wasAdded |= add(p);
    }

    return wasAdded;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean wasRemoved = false;
    for (Object o : c) {
      if (o instanceof PointXY) {
        PointXY p = (PointXY) o;
        wasRemoved |= remove(p);
      }
    }

    return wasRemoved;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    ContinuousLineSet cls = new ContinuousLineSet();

    for (Object o : c) {
      if (o instanceof PointXY && ps.contains(o)) {
        PointXY p = (PointXY) o;
        cls.add(p);
      }
    }

    int oldSize = ps.size();
    ps = cls.ps;
    fullPath = cls.fullPath;

    return size() != oldSize;
  }

  @Override
  public void clear() {
    ps.clear();
    fullPath = 0;
  }   
}

class PointXY { 
  public static PointXY of(int x, int y) {
    return new PointXY(x, y);
  }

  public final int x, y;
  private int hash;
  private boolean wasHashInit = false;

  private PointXY(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof PointXY))
      return false;
    PointXY p = (PointXY) obj;
    return x == p.x && y == p.y;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    if (!wasHashInit) {
      hash = 17;
      hash = 31 * hash + y;
      hash = 31 * hash + x;
      wasHashInit = true;
    }

    return hash;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

public class Point implements Comparable

{
...

...
@Override

public int compareTo(Pointarg0) 
{

```
    ....
```

}

...
}

...